# Why is my bicubic interpolation of discrete data looking ugly?

Tags: image-processing, bicubic

i have a 128x128 array of elevation data (elevations from -400m to 8000m are displayed using 9 colors) and i need to resize it to 512x512. I did it with bicubic interpolation, but the result looks weird. In the picture you can see original, nearest and bicubic. Note: only the elevation data are interpolated not the colors themselves (gamut is preserved). Are those artifacts seen on the bicubic image result of my bad interpolation code or they are caused by the interpolating of discrete (9 steps) data?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx2cl.png

Comment: What software are you using to do the bicubic interpolation?

Comment: i'm using this guy's library: [link](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/BiCubicSpline.html)<br/>and this guy's code snippet: [link](http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic)<br/>but both produce the same result so eiter i'm wrongly implementing them or the bicubic interpolation isn't suited for this case. Anyway there is 3rd one i'm gonna try: [link](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/java/Bicubic.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the bicubic code you're using. Here's my result with Python:

[image: Bicubic resize]

The black border around the outside is where the result was outside of the palette due to ringing.

Here's the program that produced the above:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(r'c:\temp\temp.png')

# convert the image to a grayscale with 8 values from 10 to 17
levels=((0,0,255),(1,255,0),(255,255,0),(255,0,0),(255,175,175),(255,0,255),(1,255,255),(255,255,255))
img = Image.new('L', im.size)
iml = im.load()
imgl = img.load()
colormap = {}
for i, color in enumerate(levels):
    colormap[color] = 10 + i
width, height = im.size
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        imgl[x,y] = colormap[iml[x,y]]

# resize using Bicubic and restore the original palette
im4x = img.resize((4*width, 4*height), Image.BICUBIC)
palette = []
for i in range(256):
    if 10 <= i < 10+len(levels):
        palette.extend(levels[i-10])
    else:
        palette.extend((i, i, i))
im4x.putpalette(palette)
im4x.save(r'c:\temp\temp3.png')
```

**Edit:** Evidently Python's Bicubic isn't the best either. Here's what I was able to do by hand in Paint Shop Pro, using roughly the same procedure as above.

[image: Bicubic in Paint Shop Pro]

Comment: This looks exactly as i wish for. So the bicubic is alright. Now i know where the problem is and can move on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While bicubic interpolation can sometimes generate interpolating values outside the original range (can you verify if this is happening to you?) It really seems like you may have a bug, but it is hard to say without looking at the code. As a general rule the bicubic solution should be smoother than the nearest neighbor solution.

**Edit:** I take that back, I see no interpolating values outside the original range in your images. Still, I think the strange part is the "jaggedness" you get when using bicubic, you may want to double check that.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I don't think that's the case here judging by the sample.

Comment: Yeah... It is not that. The jaggedness is strange, though.

Comment: The sea has elevation value of -9999 to differ it from land at zero height so the grey dots (undersea level) are ok. Yes, the jaggedness is the problem. I will do bicubic on the colors to check the routines. And i could post the code but don't wanna bother you with that.